# How to inherit page query string into static resources without inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, query-string

I have a static html page, with some simple css and js files. When we use this page, we need a token in the url, because security reason. For example: `http://example.com/statichtmlpage.html?token=42` 
When the token is correct, the server can serve it, else access denied. Same with other static resource, for example css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?token=42" />
```

When the token correct, the server can serve it, else access denied. Inline javascript solution is wrong, because we have a CSP header, and it forbids these scripts. We use only external resources.
This files served as static resource, without any dynamic modification. So there is no PHP or other server side tool.

How can inherit the main page query string into the static resource? If one external javascript works, then I can manage all of resurce well. But I cant access any script without token.

I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Does the tokens dynamically created? do they shown on url?

Comment: This page used in an embed browser, which can add this token to the url. And another use case in an iframe where the token is handled by the top frame. And yes, this token generated dynamically. It never visible for the user

Comment: Have you tried something like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?token=<? echo $_GET['token']; ?>" />`

Comment: There is no PHP on this server "This files served as static resource, without any dynamic modification. So there is no PHP or other server side tool." this is a simple nginx static serve,  just we have a proxy for check token. This check is a 3rd party app.